# How to add checkboxes to a JTable which uses a model with values from a database?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable, checkboxlist

I have a model(AbstracTableModel) which I use to build a JTable. 
The thing is that the table cell values seen in the GUI are displayed from a database.

How can I add a new column with checboxes for each row of the table? 
Is there a concrete answer to this?

Comment: 1. read Oracle tutorial - how to use Tables, Boolean value stored in XxxTableModel represents JCheckBox in the JTables view, 2. each 3rd - 4th. question here, tagged by JTable is about..., 3. voting to close as too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing is that the table cell values seen in the GUI are displayed from a database.

Use a `DefaultTableModel` to store the data from the database.

See the `TableFromDatabaseExample.java` code found in [Table From Database](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for simple code to load the `DefaultTableModel`.

> How can I add a new column with checboxes for each row of the table?

You can modify the above code to add an extra column to the "columnNames" Vector. Then in the looping code you add a Boolean.FALSE object to the "row" Vector.

Or, after creating the `DefaultTableModel` with the data from the database you can use the `addColumn(...)` method of the `DefualtTableModel` to create your column of check boxes.